# image compression reducer

Tags: html, compression, photoshop

I am trying to have High quality Images on my site like these ones in the slider here http://www.viewbug.com/ but when I have the actual  of the picture, it wont load fast enough, due to the big size. I tried to re size it with photoshop but the quality of my photo would decreased  a lot . so for example the following picture on this site http://www.viewbug.com/media/featured/2892642_large.jpg is high quality but small in size 377 kb, and then they re-size it with html code height = 900 and width =640 without ruing the ration dimension and it looks just fine inside the slider. I googled and I didnt find any javascript or html code that does this. how can I compress my images without loosing the quality

Comment: This isn't really on-topic for this site as it currently stands. You should think about rephrasing it. (Some tips, though: You should always serve images at the size they're going to be seen. You should look at using browser caching. Don't bother looking at compression for a .jpg image -- it won't help.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a photographer, so I do this a lot. I export my images with compression settings that are invisible to the eyes, but reduce images far smaller than the original. Unfortunately, Photoshop uses a different compression scale than most JPEG programs (and JPEG is the only efficient and compatible photograph format for the Internet), and so for Photoshop, one needs to use specific instructions.

Try this tutorial:

http://inobscuro.com/tutorials/optimizing-images-for-web-35/

Comment: Hey, Thanks I have tried that but doesnt work, I am basically  trying for this but aint working yet http://imgbond.com/contest/

Comment: You can play with the JPEG compression level. You can reduce file sizes at least 10x below the original RAW data without visible effects. But you might have some other settings in your export that are causing your image quality to go down. For example, you might want to make sure that you have your export settings properly configured to "sharpen for screen." If you don't have that set, then the images appear to be a huge amount less sharp.

Comment: hey, where do you set that sharpen on photoshop? sorry for being newbi at this

Comment: Just do export and select the sharpening option for screen. Don't sharpen your images ahead of time before exporting. (I.e., don't use any of the unsharp mask options or anything like that). Your images need the sharpening step in exporting only in order to match what you already see when looking at your original high-quality photos.

Answer (score -1):

so by using punypng u can get the solution for dat. PunyPNG is a free website optimization tool that dramatically reduces the file size of your images without any loss of quality.

Comment: is that the only one? This seems to be not free

Comment: A website optimization tool like that is not what you are looking for when specifically talking about preparing photographic images for your website. Photoshop is much more powerful, using its built-in "save for web" options.